# How to execute multiple commands using ternary syntax in Perl?

Tags: perl, if-statement

How can I do something like the following:

```
(condition) ? (do this) (do this too) : (just do this then)
```

Comment: Anyway, my attempt failed. Not sure where I went wrong...

Comment: Why not just use the regular `if` statement flow control? That's far neater and more readable. You haven't explained why you want to use the value-yielding ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 10):

Do this and this too with `do`.

```
condition ? do { this(); this_too(); } : the_other_thing()
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
( (do this), (do this too) )
```

Answer (score -3):

A sample program that does that follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $a = 1;

$result = ($a > 1) ? (print "\nDo this\n") ? (print "\nDo this also\n") ? "" : 
          (print "\nOr else do this\n");


$a = 6;

$result = ($a > 1) ? (print "\nDo this\n") ? (print "\nDo this also") ? "" : 
          (print "\nOr else do this\n");
```